# Get value of encrypted data from hiera-eyaml into puppet template

Tags: puppet, hiera, eyaml

Puppet 7

I have a template:

```
[nondefault]
aws_secret_access_key = <%= scope().call_function('lookup', 
 ['profile::aws::app_environment::secret_key']) %>
aws_access_key_id     = <%= scope().call_function('lookup', 
 ['profile::aws::app_environment::access_key']) %>
```

I deploy the template like so:

```
file { 'kms_config.yaml':
     path    => "${homedir}/.aws/credentials",
     content => template('puppet/server/aws_creds.erb'),
     ensure  => file,
     mode    => '0600',
     owner   => 'root'
 }
```

which results in:

```
# cat .aws/credentials
[nondefault]
aws_secret_access_key = Sensitive [value redacted]
aws_access_key_id     = Sensitive [value redacted]
```

My question is, how do I get the actual value, instead of `Sensitive [value redacted]`, in the file?

Comment: This is likely to be a matter of class `profile::aws::app_environment`, which you have not presented, not particularly of Hiera or its eyaml backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> which results in:
>
> ```
> # cat .aws/credentials
> [nondefault]
> aws_secret_access_key = Sensitive [value redacted]
> aws_access_key_id     = Sensitive [value redacted]
> ```

Presumably, this is because `$profile::aws::app_environment::secret_key` and `$profile::aws::app_environment::access_key` have data type `Sensitive`.

> My question is, how do I get the actual value, instead of Sensitive [value redacted], in the file?

I haven't used `Sensitive` much, and I suspect that it was not intended to interact with templates in the way you show, but there are at least three possible solutions:

1. Use Puppet's [`unwrap`](https://www.puppet.com/docs/puppet/7/function.html#unwrap) function in your template to extract the underlying values from the `Sensitive` objects; OR
2. Create ordinary (non-parameter<sup>*</sup>) class variables in `profile::aws::app_environment` to store the wanted values as plain strings (you might even have such already).  Retrieve the values of those instead of the values of the variables you are now referencing. OR
3. Change the data types of `$profile::aws::app_environment::secret_key` and `$profile::aws::app_environment::access_key` to `String`.  Note well that this has security implications, but those may be moot under the circumstances because it looks like you'll be recording the cleartext values in a file on the target machine's filesystem.

---

<sup>*</sup> You don't want to use class parameters for this because that would defeat the purpose of the existing variables being `Sensitive` (see option (3)).

Answer (score 0):

Best approach is to use `unwrap()` or `.unwrap` [function](https://www.puppet.com/docs/puppet/8/function.html#unwrap) where applicable in puppet/template code. Works also for common `String` (simply prints it).

```
aws_access_key_id     = <%= unwrap($access_key) %>
aws_secret_access_key = <%= $secret_access_key.unwrap %>
```

Types can be easily configured to accept both `Sensitive` and `String`:

```
Variant[String, Sensitive[String]] $db_password
```

In Hiera you should be using `alias` to reference `Sensitive` value:

```
aws::secret_key: "%{alias('profile::aws::app_environment::secret_key')}"
```

Note, in order to encrypt data in transit you should be using:

```
lookup_options:
  profile::aws::app_environment::secret_key:
    convert_to: Sensitive
  '^\w+_password$':
    convert_to: Sensitive
```